# Advice on planting potatoes with long sprouts

Tags: planting, potatoes

We have a bunch of potatoes with long sprouts from their eyes.  (Actually, we just planted them, but I'll ask the questions I had right before planting.)

- Should I leave a 12-inch sprout from the eye, or break some of it off?  On average, the remaining potato chunk is small (<1"), so I imagine it doesn't have too much energy left.
- Should I plant the sprouts up or down?  (We actually planted them sideways because we weren't sure.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long sprouts may mean the potatoes were improperly stored or stored too long.  What you did is a sensible thing.   If the potatoes are not too far gone, you should get some plants to sprout.  Breaking the sprout risks breaking off the meristem; it is possible there may be other viable meristems along the sprout which could cause a plant to grow, but this is not a sure thing.

Comment: And up or down, does it matter?

Comment: down is not  a great idea, because they will have to upward again.  Your sideways strategy is probably best.